# spago docs only for project files

Tags: documentation, purescript, spago

When I run `spago docs`, the documentation is generated for **every** dependencies in my project.

Is it possible to generate a documentation only for project files?
So only for .purs files in src.

I am aware that this can lead to incomplete documentation (and type definitions that are no links), as my files also use dependencies. But it would still be helpful if the documentation was limited to the "top-level" modules of the project.

EDIT: I use spago version `0.21.0`